# SELECT & UPDATE according to status in one sql

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how to do this:

At the moment I have this, as you can see I am selecting all the `status 0 & 2`, then later in the code updating `status 0 to 97` and status `2 to 99`

```
SELECT id_queue, status FROM table WHERE status IN (0,2) ORDER BY status, id_queue ASC FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue= " + id_sms + ";

UPDATE table SET status = 99 WHERE id_queue= " + id_sms + ";
```

I want to `SELECT & UPDATE`, and also get the row ids of `id_queue` for later use
Can anyone help?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET status = CASE status WHEN 0 THEN 97
                         WHEN 2 THEN 98
             END
WHERE status IN (0, 2)
```

If you want to save the id_queue values, then you'll either need to create a temp table, or store them in your program outside the database. I'd do the second for most reasonably sized set - a lot less housekeeping if you can keep them in scope in your program.

Comment: What about selecting the ids from the table (id_queue), I still need them for something else